# jquery the width of the item doesn't match the assigned variable

Tags: jquery, var, assign

I do a simple operation:

```
var flip = windowMenoMenu*25/100;
alert(flip)
```

after i assigned this value to an element:

```
$(".flip-container").width(flip);
```

But  the .flip-container width is different to the print value...

why???

Comment: Don't know. Please create a [mcve], show us your HTML structure too, and if possible create a stack-snippet ([edit] your post and click ctrl+m)

Comment: How different is it?  if it's a rounding error, note that `.width()` rounds values to the nearest integer; `$('.foo').width(100.6); console.log($('.foo').width())` logs 101 for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you can share console.logs or more info to help debug the problem that would be easier. in the meantime you can try this as well:

```
 $(".flip-container").css({ width : flip + "px" });
```